# Subtraction universe and A set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How big is the universe where we can visualize sets in the form of Venn diagrams? If I have a finite set A can I find the U-A or I write it down as U-A? Is A-U always a set without any elements?

Comment: I would advise you to be a little bit careful when talking about a *universe* in the setting of both naive set theory and formal set theories, since it is well-known that such a concept gives a new [contradiction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set#:~:text=Russell's%20paradox,-Main%20article%3A%20Russell's&text=%2C%20the%20set%20of%20all%20sets,contain%20itself%2C%20and%20vice%20versa) every 5 seconds. So if you have the time, I would suggest getting your hands on some basic set theory book and starting from there.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri  They could be talking about a universe of discourse, which need not be a set, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @user400188, and I did not say that they were taking the universe to be a set, although I think that they are, since they are asking about it's size and bigness. Just by judging from the question, I thought maybe if the OP has some elementary exposure to set theory, they might get a better grasp of what we actually mean by a universe in set theory, which is the class of all sets.